# If String and Array are implemented as struct, does that mean their size are also limited by stack size?

Tags: swift

In Swift, `String` and `Array` are implemented as `struct`

And, `struct` is being created in stack memory.

And, stack memory has very limited size ([Is the stack size of iPhone fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929305/is-the-stack-size-of-iphone-fixed)), compared to heap memory.

Does that also mean?

1. The length of `String` is limited by stack memory size?
2. The total size of all elements hold by `Array`, is limited by stack memory size?

Comment: Hint: See what happens when you do `print(MemoryLayout<Array<Int>>.size)`

Comment: Note that `struct` doesn't have to be created in stack. If `struct` is a property of a class, it won't be created on stack. Also note that even when something is created on stack, it doesn't mean it will leave there forever. Stack variables are usually temporary.

Comment: @Sulthan Good point. That's obvious now that I think about it, but I never noticed it. So it's better to say that "structs are allocated in-line", whether that be within an a heap allocated object, or a stack allocated local variable, or a global constants section of the app binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array`, `String` and every other dynamically sized-collection (`ArraySlice`, `Substring`, `Set`, `Dictionary`, etc.) are implemented as structs that contain a reference to a heap-allocated buffer.

Almost everything that `Array` does is functionality that already exists on its internal buffer. But the `Array` struct is responsible for implementing the copy-on-write functionality that's so pervasively relied-upon in the Swift world.