# Will using struct over class, will have impact on the allowable data size?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, I'm designing a note taking app.

Its overall usage should be

```
class Note {
    var title: String?
    var body: String?
}

var notes = [Note]() 
notes.append(Note())
```

I have strong temptation to design Note as struct

```
struct Note {
    var title: String?
    var body: String?
}

var notes = [Note]() 
notes.append(Note())
```

But, I also worry that might impose limit on the

1. Maximum allowable size per Note instance. As, it is uncommon, for the Note's string body has >10MB
2. Maximum allowable array size, for Array of Note struct

As far as I know, instance of struct is created at stack memory, and instance of class is created in heap memory. Stack memory size is much more smaller than heap memory size - [Is the stack size of iPhone fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929305/is-the-stack-size-of-iphone-fixed)

Will using struct over class, will have impact on the allowable data size?

Comment: As pointed out in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56919594/1187415) to your previous question, String and Array are *fixed-sized structs* with pointers to heap-allocated memory containing the actual characters or array elements. So `struct Note` has a fixed size, independent of the number of characters stored in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no.

There is no difference in the maximum sizes of structs versus classes, or arrays of structs or classes.

Besides, as Martin said in his comment, your struct/class actually contains *pointers* to strings, not the strings themselves. Thus neither structs nor classes change size with different-sized strings.